# Managing local changes in git I never want to commit

Tags: git

So I have versions of files i have changed, these are very personal changes (for example turning minification off for a javascript build) That I am never going to commit. 
But I do want to leave it open for updating with other peoples changes.

Currently I have to do a stack save every time I update my workspace which is getting very annoying.

There must be a way to do this, please what is it?

EDIT

I still want other peoples changes to be reflected when i do a git pull, so I can't simply ignore these files.

EDIT 2
I am a contractor and can't start telling them to change the way they organise their git repo. The file I have explicitly change is gruntfile.js a build file.

Comment: Do you or do you not want these config files to be updated when you do a git pull.  Possible to have it either way, more difficult to have it both ways.

Comment: I would remove the files from git and ignore them from the repo. Then if someone updates those files elsewhere, those changes need to be communicated.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do want them to be updated.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well they are already in git. i am a contractor in this company so have no control over how they wish to do things.  And if i set 'git ignore' there is no communication as everyone expects the changes to happen automatically with a git pull.

Comment: @caramba thanks for belittling me. I was referring to the OP’s desire to keep “personal changes” of what initially seemed like config files.

Comment: @caramba How would you keep personal edits to config files, yet allowing changes from others? Removing them from vcs seems to be an obvious solution.

Comment: @evolutionxbox [did you see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48883808/2008111)?

Comment: @caramba I am completely confused by your comment " '"if someone updates those files elsewhere, those changes need to be communicated' (facepalm) ..." Were you talking to me or evolution box?  If you were talking to me I trying to explain why I couldn't just add it to git ignore. Which I knew somebody would advise (and infact has). And adding it to git ignore Just for me now creates a different file that will produce conflicts.

Comment: @WendyG I was talking to evolutionxbox. But do you understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48883808/2008111)? Of course conflicts need to be solved. But for future everybody can work on the same files and have hes "local/personalized" setup. Local/personalized setup will never be commited.

Comment: @caramba I understand but I was hoping for a solution that i could use in solo, as everyone else it seems is happy with the situation.

Comment: @WendyG what about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476252/alternate-grunt-js-tasks-for-development-production-environments ?

Comment: @caramba, so there isn't actually an answer to my question, there isn't a git flag, or setting or gizmo that allows me to continue working the way i want to.

Comment: @WendyG if your question is can I click somewhere to set things up I guess then the answer is no. But the „flag“ you want can easily be accomplished with the steps mentioned in my and other answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165507/discussion-between-wendyg-and-caramba).

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the config file named `myConfig.yml.dist` (dist for distribution) where all and everyone makes changes and pushes them to version control system.

But then lets say you have the databases password which has to be in the `myConfig.yml` but you never want to push the password to a version control system. But you need it locally to have your application work. Also your local database password might not be the same as the one running live.

So the trick is that everyone ignores the `myConfig.yml` so your `.gitignore` file should contain one line saying

```
/config/myConfig.yml
```

But if someone adds a new parameter he has to add it in the `myConfig.yml.dist` file. And he will commit and push it. Cause everyone need to know about it. But you kind of just have keys with dummy data and or comments in `myConfig.yml.dist`. So basically you can copy `myConfig.yml.dist` to `myConfig.yml` add the right passwords and your application runs.

Answer (score 0):

A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. If you create a file in your repository named .gitignore, Git uses it to determine which files and directories to ignore, before you make a commit.

Navigate to the location of your Git repository and create a .gitignore file (if it is not created before). Add the folder name or file name which you want to untrack from commit.
Sample .gitignore file

```
vendor
css/main.css.map
```

Here vendor is folder and main.css.map is file. Now it will ignore 'vendor' and main.css.map during commit.

**.gitignore file should be committed into your repository, in order to share the ignore rules with any other users that clone the repository.**

Comment: *Now it will ignore 'vendor' and main.css.map during commit.* -- `git commit` doesn't care about the [`ignore` files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). `git status`, `git add` and `git rm` use them.

Comment: They already have a .gitignore file which is in version control, so if I add my files to it, i just move the problem to the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

If the config file allows import from other config files, then you can create two configs like `main.config` and `personalized.config`. And in the `main.config` import `personalized.config`.

After this, you can add `personalized.config` in the `.gitignore` file.
This way, `main.config` will contain all the config that should be sent with everyone and `personalized.config` will contain config specific to you only.

Make sure you add import statement at appropriate place maybe towards end of the `main.config` file.

I have used it when config is defined in python file.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean specifically just this sort of config file, I include ant files, maven poms, grunt files Etc. within the category of config files.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but can't you have a local branch for doing work in that has your 'never-to-be-pushed' work committed, and then undo the changes within the merge commit to master?

Then... you have this working branch to continue pulling from master and committing to, but you have to merge it to master and push from master -- i think -- please confirm if anyone knows 1) you have to push from master, 2) future pulls from master won't remove the local changes.