# Maintain git with different settings.py for development and production

Tags: python, django, git

I have a Bitbucket repo which interacts with my remote server to push production code for my live Django website. However I want to interact with my Bitbucket repo from my local desktop repo -  where I want to test development code before pushing to my Bitbucket which is my production.

The only file I don't want to push from my local repo is `settings.py` as it's different for production and development. I can't add it to `.gitignore` as I still need it to be pushed from my bitbucket repo to my remote server. Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing local changes in git I never want to commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883529/managing-local-changes-in-git-i-never-want-to-commit)

Comment: The duplicate question has a good answer which should help you.